# Best way to generate random data into a database

Tags: sql, database, random

What is the best method to generate random data in SQL database lke name surnames tel no etc?

Is there any tool available that can do this for you?

Basically I have a database and I would like to fill it out with demo data....

Thanks!

Comment: What RDBMS? [For SQL Server](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If SQL Server [Redgate SQL Server SQL Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/) does this.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.generatedata.com/

This tool gives us the ability to download in a variety of formats, including the command for inclusion in the database